# Trying to output a mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

I'm trying to test outputting data from a database table using phpmyadmin in php. For some reason it isn't working though, no errors involved.  What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a picture of my database:

[image: database]

Note: This database is filled with fake information, no real e-mail addresses are used.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

    include "cs234DbConnect.inc.php";

    $dbc =  mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPWD, DBNAME);
    $error = mysqli_connect_error();
    if($error != null){
        $output= "<p> Unable to connect to database<p>" . $error;
        exit($output);
    }


    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM site7_customers WHERE FirstName = 'Leonie'") or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $FirstName = $rows['FirstName'];
        $LastName = $rows['LastName'];
        $Email = $rows['Email']


        echo "$FirstName $LastName<br>$Email<br><br>";

    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);


    ?>
```

Here is how I'm connecting:

```
<?php
    /* File: cs234DbConnect.inc.php
    */
    define('DBNAME', 'mtingle');
    define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
    define('DBUSER', 'mtingle');
    define('DBPWD'', 'mypassword');

    define('DBCONN', 'mysql:host=' . DBHOST . ';dbname=' . DBNAME);
    ?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I commented on your answer, and said I changed the above code to show it.

Comment: You should always make an "edit" and mark it as an "edit" when modifying a question, while keeping your original question/code intact. People will see my answer and say "there's nothing wrong with OP's code".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [**your originally posted question/code**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26536998/1) should any be wondering.

The reason being is that you're not connecting to your query.

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT...
```

missing `$dbc` connection variable to it.

do

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT...
```

Having used

`or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()` would have thrown you an error.

**Edit:** after you posted your `cs234DbConnect.inc.php` content

Remove `define('DBCONN', 'mysql:host=' . DBHOST . ';dbname=' . DBNAME);` from inside your file, that is PDO syntax.

and `define('DBPWD'', 'mypassword');`  (extra quote)

to `define('DBPWD', 'mypassword');`

you also missed a semi-colon at the end of `$Email = $rows['Email']`

*Thanks Meda.*

---

Plus, using your present method is open to SQL injection,  [**use prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Plus, that missing semi-colon should have produced a parse error.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: I've edited my code above, but I'm still getting no error when running on localhost, unsure of the cause now.

Comment: Oh lovely, you've changed your question after I posted an answer. @tonnor22 show me what's inside `include "cs234DbConnect.inc.php";` and how are you defining `(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPWD, DBNAME)`? Plus what are the errors?

Comment: I've edited the post to include how I defined it. I'm getting no errors, just a blank page.

Comment: remove `define('DBCONN', 'mysql:host=' . DBHOST . ';dbname=' . DBNAME);` that is PDO syntax.

Comment: I've removed it, and changed the definition of DBPWD

Comment: @tonnor22 I think you missed a semi-colon at `$Email = $rows['Email']`

Comment: @meda Yep, and will edit, thanks. right on both counts

Comment: Finally, I am getting an error,Unable to connect to database

Access denied for user 'mtingle'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @tonnor22 wrong credentials then. You have `mtingle` in two instances, make sure all info is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did have the wrong credentials, this solved everything.

Comment: @tonnor22 You're very much welcome. I'm glad this was resolved, *cheers*